# After Effects (Mac) Execute a Script from Terminal

Tags: macos, scripting, adobe, terminal, after-effects

I'm trying to figure out how to execute an After Effects script from the command line.

Official documentation says:

```
Example (for Windows):
afterfx -r c:\script_path\example_script.jsx
```

And nothing for Mac. However I'm trying:

```
open -b com.adobe.AfterEffects --args -r /script_path/example_script.jsx
```

And nothing happens. The program get opened though, but it seems that the script is never called.

Anyone had figured out this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this:

```
open -b com.adobe.AfterEffects --args /Users/[user]/Desktop/[folder]/file.aep
```

seems all I had to do was get rid of the 'r' flag.

Good luck!

Comment: This only opens an AEP file. It doesn't run a script. (In CS6 at least) you use AppleScript. The answer by MentalFish may have been true with CS4. But in CS6 you use DoScriptFile if you want to run a script from a file (though DoScriptFile is not in the CS6 scripting reference... thanks Adobe).

Answer (score 5):

---

This is actually documented [here](http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf)

You should now be able to use DoScriptFile (instead of DoScript) with Applescript. Something like:

```
tell application "Adobe After Effects CS6"
  DoScriptFile path/to/file.jsx
end tell
```

you can also call a specific function using external parameters by mixing this method with the one mentioned by MentalFish

- make an applescript [in this case called ASfile.scpt]:

  ```
  on run argv
      set SomeName to (POSIX file (item 1 of argv))
      tell application "Adobe After Effects CS6"
          DoScriptFile SomeName
          DoScript item 2 of argv
     end tell
  end run
  ```
- from python and assuming you have a 64bit machine you can call:

  ```
  ae = subprocess.call('arch -x86_64 osascript /AppleScriptLocation/ASfile.scpt %s/SomeScript.jsx "SomeFunction(\'%s\')"' %( ScriptsFolder, ParameterFromPython),shell=True)
  ```

Comment: I cannot believe this wasn't documented by Adobe.  You just saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently AE on Mac does not support command line execution of scripts: http://www.aenhancers.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1903

This works, create an AppleScript that tells AE to run the script via the DoScript command:

```
set test to (POSIX file ("/Users/username/Desktop/test.jsx"))
tell application "Adobe After Effects CSYourVersionNumber"
    DoScript test
end tell
```

... and run the script via the command line as such (to run it in 32-bit mode):

```
arch -i386 osascript test.applescript
```

**If you want to pass in the parameter of what script to launch you can do it like this:**

```
on run argv
    set test to (POSIX file (item 1 of argv))
    tell application "Adobe After Effects CSYourVersionNumber"
        DoScript test
    end tell 
end run
```

Run the script and pass in the path to the jsx file:

```
arch -i386 osascript test.applescript /Users/username/Desktop/test.jsx
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  Orangechicken is right, though, that the command is `DoScriptFile` and not `DoScript`

Answer (score 1):

you could place it in the startup folder (I use windows, the folder in win is Adobe After Effects CS4/Support Files/Scripts/Startup). Scripts in that folder are executed upon AfterEffects booting up.

Might be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to throw in here, some answers where great though possibly outdated.
This code:

```
on run argv
    tell application "Adobe After Effects CC 2018"
        DoScriptFile item 1 of argv
    end tell
end run
```

For the applescript file works, the POSIX code does not.
Then running it in the terminal for Mojave works like this:

```
osascript AppleScriptAETest.scpt "/Users/.../Your/file/here.jsx"
```

This works best for me.

Comment: I have an issue running script:
osascript run.scpt "/Users/admin/test/test.jsx"
run.scpt:84:88: script error: Expected end of line but found class name. (-2741)

Comment: That's odd, is that an AE error or an Applescript error?